# PySpark Development Environment in an Ubuntu 16.04 Docker Container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to establish a development environment to play around with Apache Spark, specifically `pyspark`, inside a Docker container running Ubuntu 16.04.  For the same of maintain consistent development environments when different developers contribute to code, I require all development to take place in a well-defined Docker container.

My issue is that I cannot get around the following Java error when I run the `pyspark` executable

```
rmarkbio@linuxkit-025000000001:~/project$ pyspark
Python 3.5.3+ (default, Nov 29 2017, 08:55:08) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<init>(SparkConf.scala:716)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<clinit>(SparkConf.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.$anonfun$getOption$1(SparkConf.scala:389)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.getOption(SparkConf.scala:389)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.get(SparkConf.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkHadoopUtil$$appendS3AndSparkHadoopConfigurations(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:463)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.newConfiguration(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:436)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$3(SparkSubmit.scala:334)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linuxkit-025000000001: linuxkit-025000000001: Name or service not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:946)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localIpAddress(Utils.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$localCanonicalHostName$1(Utils.scala:996)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localCanonicalHostName(Utils.scala:996)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linuxkit-025000000001: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1501)
    ... 24 more
conn_info_file:  /tmp/tmpiuwhok7q/tmplief2cba
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rmarkbio/project/spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 38, in <module>
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
  File "/home/rmarkbio/project/spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 316, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/home/rmarkbio/project/spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 46, in launch_gateway
    return _launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/home/rmarkbio/project/spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 109, in _launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
>>>
```

My `Dockerfile` is defined by

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-l", "-i", "-c" ]

# a few minor docker-specific tweaks
# see https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap
RUN set -xe \
    \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L40-L48
    && echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \
    && echo 'exit 101' >> /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \
    && chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \
    \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L54-L56
    && dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl \
    && cp -a /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d /sbin/initctl \
    && sed -i 's/^exit.*/exit 0/' /sbin/initctl \
    \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L71-L78
    && echo 'force-unsafe-io' > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/docker-apt-speedup \
    \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L85-L105
    && echo 'DPkg::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
    && echo 'APT::Update::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
    && echo 'Dir::Cache::pkgcache ""; Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
    \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L109-L115
    && echo 'Acquire::Languages "none";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-no-languages \
    \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L118-L130
    && echo 'Acquire::GzipIndexes "true"; Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order:: "gz";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-gzip-indexes \
    \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L134-L151
    && echo 'Apt::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant "false";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-autoremove-suggests

# delete all the apt list files since they're big and get stale quickly
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# this forces "apt-get update" in dependent images, which is also good
# (see also https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1699913)

# enable the universe
RUN sed -i 's/^#\s*\(deb.*universe\)$/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

# make systemd-detect-virt return "docker"
# See: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/aa0c34279ee40bce2f9681b496922dedbadfca19/src/basic/virt.c#L434
RUN mkdir -p /run/systemd && echo 'docker' > /run/systemd/container

# Python installation
RUN apt-get update && apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common vim
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.5
RUN apt-get update && export PATH
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential python3.5 python3.5-dev python3-pip python-pip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get update && pip3 install --upgrade pip==19.0.1
RUN pip3 install -U tensorflow
RUN pip3 install -U scikit-learn
RUN apt-get update && pip3 install --no-cache-dir numpy scipy pandas matplotlib
RUN pip3 install neo4j-driver

# NLTK
#RUN pip3 install nltk
#RUN python3 -c "import nltk; nltk.download('stopwords')"
#RUN cp -r /root/nltk_data /usr/share/nltk_data

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade requests==2.13.0
RUN pip3 install --upgrade oauth2client==4.0.0
RUN pip3 install neo4j-driver
RUN echo "Y" | apt-get install curl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install wget
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get install apt-transport-https
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev tdsodbc python-dev build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y freetds-common freetds-bin freetds-dev

# Spark-related installs
RUN apt-get update && echo "Y" | apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && echo "Y" | apt-get install scala
RUN wget http://apache.claz.org/spark/spark-2.4.2/spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
RUN tar zxf spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
RUN apt-get update && pip3 install pyspark
RUN apt-get update && pip3 install graphframes


# Set python 3.5 as the default for the container
RUN unlink /usr/bin/python
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python

RUN apt-get install bc

# Set root password
RUN echo "root:##rmarkbio%%" | chpasswd

# Install sudo
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install sudo

# overwrite this with 'CMD []' in a dependent Dockerfile
CMD ["/bin/bash"]

# Create and boot into a development user instead of working as root
RUN groupadd -r username -g 901
RUN useradd -u 901 -r -g username username
RUN echo "username:##username%%" | chpasswd
RUN adduser username sudo
RUN mkdir /home/username
RUN mkdir /home/username/project
RUN mkdir /home/username/logs
RUN chown -R username /home/username
USER username
WORKDIR /home/username/project
```

The image is built with something like

```
docker build -t username/image_name:v000 .
```

and the container with something like

```
        docker run -i -t \
            --entrypoint /bin/bash \
            --net="host" \
            --name=container_name \
            -v $(PWD):/home/username/project \
            -v $(PWD)/../logs:/home/username/logs \
            -v ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa \
            username/image_name:v000
```

I feel like I've check double checked every version of Java, scala, Spark and all their respective environmental variables, but I can't get this error to budge.  There are only a few online mentions of this error and none helped.  Given that mentions of this error are rare, however, I'd think there must be something simple and obvious that I'm missing because lots of people use this technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem and it's related to Docker and how it handles its hostname when inside the container.  I also have an unsatisfying workaround.

Suppose that I have `wget`ed the Spark tarball and unpacked it

https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-2.4.2/spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

After going into its directory, I can try an alternative example script that is already provided

```
./bin/run-example SparkPi 10
```

I keep running into this error:

```
rmarkbio@linuxkit-025000000001:~/project/spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7$ ./bin/run-example SparkPi 10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<init>(SparkConf.scala:716)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<clinit>(SparkConf.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.$anonfun$getOption$1(SparkConf.scala:389)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.getOption(SparkConf.scala:389)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.get(SparkConf.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkHadoopUtil$$appendS3AndSparkHadoopConfigurations(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:463)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.newConfiguration(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:436)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$3(SparkSubmit.scala:334)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linuxkit-025000000001: linuxkit-025000000001: Name or service not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:946)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localIpAddress(Utils.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$localCanonicalHostName$1(Utils.scala:996)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localCanonicalHostName(Utils.scala:996)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linuxkit-025000000001: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1501)
    ... 24 more
```

But then I found a suggestion that the part of the error saying

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linuxkit-025000000001: Name or service not known
```

means that the hostname, which here is "`linuxkit-025000000001`", is not in `/etc/hosts`.  Indeed, there it is.  I am supposed to go into that file and change

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

to

```
127.0.0.1   linuxkit-025000000001    localhost
```

and it seems to work (as far as I can tell from the voluminous output that I'll abstain from posting here).

To double check, let's try running the `pyspark` executable

```
rmarkbio@linuxkit-025000000001:~/project/spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7$ ./bin/pyspark 
Python 3.5.3+ (default, Nov 29 2017, 08:55:08) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
19/05/07 18:49:58 WARN Utils: Your hostname, linuxkit-025000000001 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.65.3 instead (on interface eth0)
19/05/07 18:49:58 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
19/05/07 18:49:58 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.2
      /_/


Using Python version 3.5.3+ (default, Nov 29 2017 08:55:08)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
```

It works!!!

So, what is the history of `linuxkit-025000000001`?  This explains it well

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2902

I want this change to be in place in `/etc/hosts` immediately upon creating a container from the image, so I need the `Dockerfile` to do it.  Unfortunately, that does not appear to be possible.

So far, I cannot find a way to do this from the `Dockerfile`; Docker seems to be set up to prevent access to `/etc/hosts` until after the container is made.  Instead, I have to settle for this initialization script that I'm calling just `init.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /etc/hosts /home/rmarkbio/project/hosts.new
sed -i "s/127.0.0.1       localhost/127.0.0.1   linuxkit-025000000001    localhost/" /home/rmarkbio/project/hosts.new
echo "somepassword" | sudo -S cp -f /home/rmarkbio/project/hosts.new /etc/hosts
rm /home/rmarkbio/project/hosts.new
echo ''
```